# Database design for types of users

Tags: database-design, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm planning a web system where there are mainly two types of users. My project is powered by Play! framework and ebean as the ORM layer.

Now, with the OOP perspective I should create a `User` Model and then two more classes which extends `User`. Another way, relatively simple is creating two different models and hence, two different DB tables.

What is the preferable way to choose and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something is and always will be a specialization of a generalization then use inheritance.

If something plays the role of something, then use composition.

Example:

An individual person is and always will be a specialization of an abstract legal party.

A person could be a customer one day, an employee the next, a supplier the next. They play those roles. Use composition in that case.

So for your users, are they permanent specializations? Or are they different kind of roles?

Comment: Well, that something I might have to consider. By the way, what's your technical definition for composition? (in this context)

Comment: A hasOne or hasMany relationship would be composition